# Cannot compare elements exception in EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have essentially:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(List<int> myIds)
{
    var myList = from entry in db.Entries
             where (myIds == null || myIds.Contains(entry.Id))
                 select entry;
    return View(myList);
}
```

The objective is to get only the items with the passed Ids or return all of them. (other criteria snipped for clarity)

I am getting a exception when I return `myList`, I have done some debugging and it occurs when doing a `.ToList()`

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'.
>   Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity
>   types are supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection\`1 Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937112/cannot-compare-elements-of-type-system-collections-generic-icollection1-only-p)

Comment: Note this was written a year and a half before its "duplicate"

Comment: Answers are more important than date of creation. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651.  If you agree that it is not obvious, please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue was because the myIds was null.

I needed to:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(List<int> myIds)
{
    if(myIds == null)
    {
        myIds = new List<int>();    
    }
    bool ignoreIds = !myIds.Any();

    var myList = from entry in db.Entries
                 where (ignoreIds || myIds.Contains(entry.Id))
                 select entry;
    return View(myList);
}
```

Comment: More specifically, it was because you were doing a null check in the 'where' clause.

Comment: Oh! thanks @htxryan. I almost missed your comment, but it saved my search for more answers

Comment: @htxryan why can't EF deal with a null check in a where clause?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner There's probably someone who could provide a more specific technical explanation, but roughly: it's because EF has to turn this LINQ query into SQL, and there is no direct translation for "List == null". It turns the "List.Contains" into an "IN" statement. The fix here was giving it a simple bool instead of the list null check, which easily translates to SQL.