# Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1 Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have written this code

```
IQueryable<Site> sites = context.MainTable.Include("RelatedTable");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1)) {
    sites = sites.Where(s => s.RelatedTable != null && s.RelatedTable.Any(p => p.Name == param1.ToLower() && p.PolicyType == "primary"));
}

foreach (string secondaryPolicy in secondaryPolicies)
{
    sites = sites.Where(s => s.RelatedTable != null && s.RelatedTable.Any(p => p.Name == secondaryPolicy.ToLower() && p.PolicyType == "secondary"));
}

return sites.ToList();
```

However at the `ToList` line I am getting the exception

> Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Project1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types,
>   enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can't compare a related table to `null` directly.  Instead, compare against your foreign key member (assuming that `PrimaryTable` reference `RelatedTable` using a member called `RelatedTableId`.

```
sites.Where(s => s.RelatedTableId != null && s.RelatedTable.Any(
    p => p.Name == param1.ToLower() && p.PolicyType == "primary"));
```

You may even be able to get away with removing the null check completely.  Since this query is run against the database, you won't get a `NullReferenceException` and it may work.  You'll have to double check on that though.

Comment: I removed the null check and the code threw a Object Not set to Reference Exception.

Comment: Strange. As an IQueryable, that shouldn't occur if you are using entities.  Anyway, does it work if you keep it in there?

Comment: You are correct. I had some other mistake in my code.

Comment: I don't get, RelatedTable is a list, how can there be any RelatedTableId? mine doesn't have this.

Comment: I was using sRelatedTable.Where(p => p.Name == param1.ToLower()).Any()
I changed it for your solutions and now is working
Thanks!

Comment: A null comparison was also my problem. Used .Any() and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

It is because that you have a null check in the where clause.

Comment: So strange and simple

Comment: This isn't right at all. Null checks get used all the time in where clauses. It's a null check against an ICollection that represents an Included tables that is the issue...

Answer (score 15):

The error can occur if navigation collection compared with null. It should be checked if Any record exist. In the particular example Any is used anyway, so check collection to null is redundant

**Incorrect**

```
dbContext.MainTable.Where(c => c.RelatedTable==null )
```

**Correct**

```
dbContext.MainTable.Where(c => !c.RelatedTable.Any() )
```

Comment: still not perfect, especially in case where object (mainTable) has null reference for nested child (relatedTable), this solution ends up with exception as Any() dont compares with null. Solution from @Nathan A looks more correct from business logic point of view.

Answer (score 5):

Collection field can be null in this case you get exception `NullReferenceException`

when use `RelatedTables.Any()`

If you add `RelatedTables != null` as in a question then you can get

> Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Project1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types,
>   enumeration types and entity types are supported.

If you get the `NullReferenceException` exception, lazy loading is not turned off and you are good with lazy loading for the field then to prevent exception mark field with `virtual` keyword to allow lazy loading for the field

```
virtual ICollection<Table> RelatedTables{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same situation. It then passed by comparing null with FirstOrDefault(). In your case, I applied as per below

```
    sites = sites.Where(s => s.RelatedTable.FirstOrDefault() != null && s.RelatedTable.Any(p => p.Name == param1.ToLower() && p.PolicyType == "primary"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Foreign Key field configured because the relationship between `MainTable` and `RelatedTable` in my case is 1 to 1. However for a 1 to many relationship  if you don't have foreign key but you have a navigation property to the `MainTable` model in the `RelatedModel` model the following solution also works.

**1 to 1**

```
  var result = from s in context.Sites
               join r in context.RelatedTable on s.Id equals r.Id
               select s; 

  return result;
```

**1 to many**

```
  var result = from s in context.Sites
               join r in context.RelatedTable on s.Id equals r.Site.Id
               into rs
               where rs.RelatedTable.Any(p => p.Name == param1.ToLower() && p.PolicyType == "primary")
               select s
```

Answer (score -1):

It work me , I just remove the null check;

correct:
result=

```html
db.EmpTable.FirstOrDefault().ProjectsAssign.Name,
```

InCorrect :
result=

```js
db.EmpTable!=null && db.EmpTable.FirstOrDefault().ProjectsAssign!=null ? 
      db.EmpTable.FirstOrDefault().ProjectsAssign.Name : null,
```