# Entity Framework Linq Query to List - Error when using contains: Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have many queries just like this one, but I can't figure out why this one is erroring. It seems like it has something to do with the parts of my where clause when I am doing the null check and then using Contains.

**The error I am getting is:**

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

And the code where it is thrown:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int? productDepartmentId = null, int? productCategoryId = null, IEnumerable<int?> productCategoryIds = null, IEnumerable<string> sections = null)
{
    using (var context = new AppContext())
    {
        var retList = (from obj in context.Products
                       where (productDepartmentId == null || obj.ProductDepartmentId == productDepartmentId) &&
                             (productCategoryId == null || obj.ProductCategoryId == productCategoryId) &&
                             (productCategoryIds == null || productCategoryIds.Contains(obj.ProductCategoryId)) &&
                             (sections == null || sections.Contains(obj.sections))
                       select obj).ToList();
        return retList;
    }
}
```

These are the lines that are making it error. I believe it doesn't like the null check:

```
(productCategoryIds == null || productCategoryIds.Contains(obj.productCategoryIds)) &&
(sections == null || sections.Contains(obj.Section))
```

Here is my call to the method (sections isn't being passed):

```
List<int?> categoryIds = new List<Int?>;
varList = ProductsDAL.GetProducts(productDepartmentId: productproductDeparmentId, 
                                  productCategoryId: productCategoryId, 
                                  productCategoryIds: categoryIds);
```

I have also tried passing in a List of type int.

Comment: Where is categoryIds and sections coming from?

Comment: They come from my code. They end up being comma separated lists of Ids. I noticed the problem is definitely because of the part of the where clause that has the null check and the contains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection\`1 Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937112/cannot-compare-elements-of-type-system-collections-generic-icollection1-only-p)

Comment: Can you post the Product class as well?

Comment: The product class is just a basic class with some product properties auto-generated by entity framework. The main thing causing the error is the fact that I am doing a null check for each Contains line of the where clause. All of my other GetList functions work fine because they don't use Contains. I need to find a way so passing those lists to my function is optional and this is normally what I do.

Comment: My compiler does not throw an error on this code: http://pastebin.com/pLyAU5he

Comment: Hmm that is very strange. In my product class section is of type string and categoryId is of type nullable int

Comment: @Glorfindel that is one messed up pastebin...

Comment: Does anyone have any workarounds if I need to make these lists that I pass in optional? Because it doesn't like when I compare to null in the where clause.

Comment: @MatthewPeterson This compiles and works to produce the output "ProductCount: 1": http://ideone.com/fSOr3u what is different about your code?

Comment: I am not sure I am using basic entity framework Db first and it auto-generated my Product class for me. It is strange because I never ran into this issue before and I swore I have used the null comparison in the where clause with contains. I guess I am going to have to look for a mistake in my code somewhere. All of the other posts similar to this are telling the person to remove null from their query.

Comment: What does the definition of `ProductDepartmentId` and `ProductCategoryId` look like in your auto-generated Product class? I'm assuming that it is just an `int?` type, which is the type the error message is displaying it is having an error with.

Comment: I think the reason that it works for me, but doesn't work for you is because in your case the linq query has to be translated into a runnable sql statement which it fails to do because something in your query is not able to be translated to SQL. In my opinion it is the `productCategoryIds` parameter, I don't think an `IEnumerable<int?>` will work when it tries to translate that to SQL. Can you try to change your `productCategoryIds` parameter to `IEnumerable<int>` and see if that works?

Comment: I assume obj.sections is of type string?

Comment: Yes, obj.sections is actually singular. So it is just a string and I want to see if it is within the passed in list of sections. I tried passing in an IEnumerable<int> rather then int? and still getting the same error.

Comment: Is this error occuring during runtime or compile time? Can you include the call to the GetProducts method, so we can see what actual types are being used for the `IEnumerable<int?>` parameter, and `IEnumerable<string>` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't like the null check and you need it to be optional, you can do this:

```
List<int> productCategoryIdsTemp = new List<int>();
if (productCategoryIds != null) {
    productCategoryIdsTemp.AddRange(productCategoryIds.Where(id => id != null).Select(id => id.Value));
}
if (sections = null) { 
    sections = new List<string>();
}
```

And then in your Linq query use this:

```
(productCategoryIdsTemp.Count == 0 || productCategoryIdsTemp.Contains(obj.ProductCategoryId)) &&
(sections.Count == 0 || sections.Contains(obj.section)) &&
```

If your productCategoryIds wasn't an IEnumerable of nullable ints you could do the same as for sections. (Don't really understand how this needs to be supported instead of a list of int)

Comment: I changed it to use a list of int instead and still getting the same exact error.

Comment: It can't say the exact same error, since the original error said it can't use IEnumerable of nullable int. If you are not using that anymore, it has to be a different error now.

Comment: I meant that I am still getting an error that says this at the end sorry: Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported. I don't know what to do anymore. Could it have anything to do with the way my database table is setup since EF auto generated the Product classed based on it. productCategoryId is a nullable int property and Section is a string property.

Comment: @MatthewPeterson Have you tried my example exactly or have you tweaked it a bit? I am pretty sure my example works if you do that exactly. Can you post your current code?